# git add will not stage certain files

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

I am running msysgit 1.8.1 on Win8.  I am trying to stage some changes to a project I am working on.  I am trying to stage the changes to the vcxproj and vcxproj.filters files, but no matter what I do, they always show as unstaged.  I thought it might be a case sensitivity issue, but even using the core.ignorecase=true option doesn't make a difference.  Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

Here is a transcript of my attempt to stage one of the files.

```
C:\sdev\realtick [dev +2 ~2 -0 | +0 ~2 -0]> git status
# On branch dev
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   rtpack.props
#       modified:   rtpack.targets
#       new file:   tools/TALRGB/TalRgb32.idb
#       new file:   tools/TALRGB/packages.props
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   TOOLS/TALRGB/TalRgb.vcxproj
#       modified:   TOOLS/TALRGB/TalRgb.vcxproj.filters
#

C:\sdev\realtick [dev +2 ~2 -0 | +0 ~2 -0]> git add TOOLS/TALRGB/TalRgb.vcxproj

C:\sdev\realtick [dev +2 ~2 -0 | +0 ~2 -0]> git status
# On branch dev
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   rtpack.props
#       modified:   rtpack.targets
#       new file:   tools/TALRGB/TalRgb32.idb
#       new file:   tools/TALRGB/packages.props
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   TOOLS/TALRGB/TalRgb.vcxproj
#       modified:   TOOLS/TALRGB/TalRgb.vcxproj.filters
#
C:\sdev\realtick [dev +2 ~2 -0 | +0 ~2 -0]>
```

Comment: Daft question - but, have you tried `TOOLS\TALRGB\TalRgb.vcxproj`, with backslashes? You do seem to be working on Windows, after all.

Comment: Yeah, I tried both the backslash and forward slash, and trying the git add from the TOOLS\TALRGB\ folder.  On more digging, I think the issue is related to the fact that there is a tools\TALRGB\TalRgb.vcxproj entry in the previous commit.

Comment: Another note.  I was able to get the files staged and commited by using the GitExtensions GUI.  But I still don't know what it did differently to make it work.

Comment: Did you try adding with "tools" in lower-case?

Comment: Yes.  The problem seems to be that the files are already tracked using the path tools/TALRGB/TalRgb.vcxproj, and git can't figure out that they are the same thing, despite the ignorecase option.