# git conflict with differently cased directory name

Tags: git, case-sensitive, msysgit

I am using msysgit 1.8.1, and I am running into an issue with directory casing.  I have the core.ignorecase set to true.  But I have a case where git seems to have the folder under two different casings.  So when I do a git add -A, it picks up the change to a particular file under the path

tools\TALRGB\TalRgb.vcxproj

but the path

TOOLS\TALRGB\TalRgb.vcxproj

always shows as an untracked change.  This doesn't seem to cause any problems, but it will be an issue if I roll this out to other developers.  How can I get git to not do this?

This question is related to [git add will not stage certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687142/git-add-will-not-stage-certain-files)

Comment: I think I figured out how to fix the immediate problem.  The issue was that the wrong case filename was in the index.  Using git update-index --force-remove to remove the incorrect filenames, and then doing a git add -A resolves it.  The real question is how to prevent this from happening again.  Any ideas?

Comment: That was a useful tip -- it solved the problem for some of the files where we were seeing this same issue. Add it as an answer so I can upvote you! The other detail that I have found helpful is to set Git to be case-insensitive using `git config core.ignorecase false`